# mysql query with date comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have used following query for getting info which is greater than 2012 but I am not getting correct data with compare to date ,please give me correct query?
MYSQL QUERY:

```
SELECT a.invoiceno,
       a.invoicerefno,
       a.invoicedate,
       c.companyname,
       a.grandtotal,
       a.twempname,
       itemdescription,
       quantity
FROM twsql_twalldata.t_invoicedet a
INNER JOIN twsql_twalldata.t_salesinv_items b ON a.invoiceno=b.invoiceno
INNER JOIN twsql_twalldata.t_customerdet c ON a.customercode=c.customercode
WHERE a.twempname NOT LIKE '%Auto%'
  AND itemdescription LIKE '%AMC%'
  OR itemdescription LIKE '%annual maintenance contract%'
  AND invoicecancelled=0
  AND a.invoicedate > '2012-04-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: What is the type of invoicedate in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.invoiceno,
       a.invoicerefno,
       a.invoicedate,
       c.companyname,
       a.grandtotal,
       a.twempname,
       itemdescription,
       quantity
FROM twsql_twalldata.t_invoicedet a
INNER JOIN twsql_twalldata.t_salesinv_items b ON a.invoiceno=b.invoiceno
INNER JOIN twsql_twalldata.t_customerdet c ON a.customercode=c.customercode
WHERE a.twempname NOT LIKE '%Auto%' AND 
      (itemdescription LIKE '%AMC%' OR itemdescription LIKE '%annual maintenance contract%') AND 
       invoicecancelled=0 AND DATE(a.invoicedate) > DATE('2012-04-01');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `invoicedate` data type is datetime then you will need one correction i.e. using proper parentheses for the OR condition.

```
WHERE 
a.twempname NOT LIKE '%Auto%'
AND ( itemdescription LIKE '%AMC%' OR itemdescription LIKE '%annual maintenance contract%')
AND invoicecancelled=0
AND a.invoicedate > '2012-04-01 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
 AND a.invoicedate > '2012-04-01 00:00:00';
```

to:

```
 AND a.invoicedate >  STR_TO_DATE('2012-04-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d' %h:%i:%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you don't have required parentheses, i.e your OR condition should be placed inside brackets.

```
SELECT a.invoiceno,
       a.invoicerefno,
       a.invoicedate,
       c.companyname,
       a.grandtotal,
       a.twempname,
       itemdescription,
       quantity
FROM twsql_twalldata.t_invoicedet a
INNER JOIN twsql_twalldata.t_salesinv_items b ON a.invoiceno=b.invoiceno
INNER JOIN twsql_twalldata.t_customerdet c ON a.customercode=c.customercode
WHERE a.twempname NOT LIKE '%Auto%'
  AND (itemdescription LIKE '%AMC%' OR itemdescription LIKE '%annual maintenance contract%')
  AND invoicecancelled=0
  AND a.invoicedate > '2012-04-01';
```

Second issue could be that you invoicedate is not of type `date` or `datetime` then you need to first convert it to `date` and then compare it

```
AND STR_TO_DATE(a.invoicedate, '%Y-%m-%d') > '2012-04-01';
```

If it's the second case i would sugget that you make that field date or datetime.